# Pjsip2.2 PJSUA2 API for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c++, pjsip

I've upgraded `pjsip 2.2` with the new `PJSUA2 API`.

It's written in C++ and the [documentation](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/intro_pjsua2.html) has given the use example for Java/Python applications as well. But I can't find any example for iOS application.

I'm not very familiar with using C++ in Objective-C. I was trying to replace the existing `pjsua.h` with `pjsua2.hpp`... It seems not even linked to the lib.

Any advice?

Comment: did you had some success making it work?

Comment: @NicolasManzini nope. stay with C for now.

Comment: Had anyone got success in this? (No good documentation is available)